# What are other "Home" areas this site can branch to?

Tags: discussion

I am really off and on posting questions or answers to the site.  I might come on most days but when traversing through a page of electrical questions nothing really intrigues me to look or participate. The top two tags are Electrical 8510 and Wiring 3612. Those two tags plus # 4 Lighting 1705 are as big as the next 9 tags combined.

Background on this:  I am licensed electrician in a few cities, not an electrician by trade.   There are many many guys on here that offer great advice in electrical issues.   On 90% of the electrical issues I understand the issue/answer from post title.   I do look at the other 10% to get insight, but again don't really think about answering most (unless I feel like a common man's dummy response would help) because there are at least 10 guys that will do a better job.   Also note I am the user on the site with most points without electrical in their top 3 - not a humblebrag just saying the top user without electrical is kind of turned off from site based on questions coming in.

**So what categories or other home related things can be added to draw more than electrical issue questions out?**

And related side note...

This is not about how the site is run.   Honestly using SE for years this might be the best run site I have seen.   There are people I often don't agree with, and sure there are those that always don't agree with me but there is a respect among users.   The site is well run.

Honestly it should be the model site as far as top users/moderators.   The other sites have gone too political, too SE heavy, and too mod heavy.   I was a little sad a few years back when I was working with SE sales on getting an Enterprise solution, I answer a question and mention that women are treated a certain way in a certain religion, and BOOM.   100 mods (many SE employees) barraging me in Meta and then getting caught in an edit lie that was made to make me look bad - but I had a screenshot.   Needless to say SE employees lost a lot of revenue for their company and could learn something from moderation/process on this site.   But we have to get more than electrical questions coming in/looked at.

Comment: This is a good discussion topic to improve DIY.SE, but I got distracted with the unrelated side note about other SE sites and SE employees (do we need that remark on here?).

Comment: @AndrewT. - I think it is related because I have a long history contributing and using SE.   Giving this background shows that the issue this site has getting numbers isn't a people/mod issue but more of a realm issue.   Anyone can say this but I can say it with relevance and examples.b

Answer (score 1):

> Background on this: I am licensed electrician in a few cities, not an electrician by trade. There are many many guys on here that offer great advice in electrical issues.

Personally, I don't let *not being an electrician*, or any other particular trained expert, stop me at all. I **do** try to answer carefully, but I will often answer electrical questions based on my own experiences (as a homeowner doing some of my own electrical work and as a computer professional often called upon to do low-voltage network & phone wiring, which has significant overlap with certain areas of electrical work) and based on learning from others here and elsewhere (e.g., my own electrician). When I see a question (electrical or otherwise) where I have the concept of an answer but am not 90%+ certain that I have it correct - or I know the basics but not all the necessary details - then I will just comment instead, but I do that to help move things along in the right direction, at least until the pros step in.

On a related note, I am proud that my current top 2 answers are safety-related (and happen to be non-electrical). My 3rd top answer is electrical but the type of answer that doesn't require a licensed electrician to answer [Why do single electrical receptacles exist?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/158243/why-do-single-electrical-receptacles-exist/158249#158249)

> (unless I feel like a common man's dummy response would help)

Actually, I think those responses, well worded, can be quite useful. I am often that "common man". I try to word answers as reasonably non-technical as I can. The extensive details offered on some answers by the pros are often quite appropriate, but many times the OP really just needs a simple "why" or a very basic answer to "is this practical so I can get a pro to do the work without it costing a fortune".

I also jump in on "lost neutral" or similar safety issues, where getting the answer out there clearly & **quickly** is potentially very important.

> So what categories or other home related things can be added to draw more than electrical issue questions out?

The question really might be phrased as: **Why does electrical get so many questions compared to other topics?**

IMHO:

- Trades requiring specialized knowledge and, in most areas, with significant licensing requirements to do work outside your own residence, are going to prompt a lot of questions because people simply don't have the knowledge themselves and can't just get started based on a "hunch" (and when they do get started based on a hunch, they often come here to say "I put in a new ceiling fan and now it doesn't work"). This typically means **electrical** and **plumbing**.
- Electrical vs. Plumbing:

  - Electrical affects every room in every building - including garages, bedrooms, outbuildings such as sheds, etc. Plumbing is primarily for kitchens and bathrooms, with occasional wells thrown in - all of which have significant electrical requirements too.
  - Electrical can be expanded - e.g., add a new outlet or ceiling light where there was none before - without other major work (just a few holes to patch). Adding new plumbing fixtures is typically far more involved and therefore usually only part of major renovations (e.g., add a basement bathroom or expand a kitchen), so there are a lot more opportunities for the typical DIY to tackle an electrical project.
  - Electrical requirements have changed more over the years - e.g., AFCI, GFCI, LED lights requiring newer dimmers, smart switches, etc. - than plumbing (PEX as an alternative to copper & PVC - but not relevant to most people unless they want to replace all their piping; on-demand water heaters - but those have electrical issues >= plumbing issues)

So I'm not at all surprised to see electrical at the top of common questions - and in the nature of emergency repairs (lost neutral, problem after replacing a switch, etc.), minor upgrades (add a receptacle or light or (planning properly) replacing a fan, etc.) and major projects (kitchen, bath, shed/garage subpanel, etc.)

> This is not about how the site is run. Honestly using SE for years this might be the best run site I have seen. There are people I often don't agree with, and sure there are those that always don't agree with me but there is a respect among users. The site is well run.
>
> Honestly it should be the model site as far as top users/moderators.

I have been quite happy with the way this site is run. When I have made a mistake I have generally been treated well (and on my part I will remove or modify an answer if I know I was wrong). There is only one time I recall getting a nasty response from someone - and other regulars jumped in to my defense, which was really nice.